# How to compute the seconds-order partial derivatives of Gaussion copula?

Tags: probability

How to compute the following seconds-order  partial derivatives of u and v for Gaussion copula?Thanks
[image]

Comment: You will get more help from a wider audience if you give the formula. Then people not familiar with [Gaussian copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) can answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copula is a multivariate distribution function with uniform marginals.  It is used to impose or alter the dependence structure of a set of random variables with known marginal distributions. The density of a bivariate copula is the mixed second partial derivative.

Differentiate with respect to $u$ using Leibniz's rule.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v;\rho)\\=\frac{d}{du}\Phi^{-1}(u)\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(v)}\exp\left[-\frac1{2}\frac{y^2-2\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)y+\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{1-\rho^2}\right]\,dy.$$

Do the integration directly by completing a square.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(v)}\exp\left[-\frac1{2}\frac{y^2-2\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)y+\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{1-\rho^2}\right]\,dy\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(v)}\exp\left[-\frac1{2}\frac{[y-\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)]^2+(1-\rho^2)\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{1-\rho^2}\right]\,dy.$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v;\rho)=\frac{d}{du}\Phi^{-1}(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }\exp\left[-\frac{\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{2}\right]\Phi\left[\frac{\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right].$$

The derivative of the inverse standard normal distribution is

$$\frac{d}{du}\Phi^{-1}(u)=\frac1{\Phi'(\Phi^{-1}(u))}=\frac1{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }\exp\left[-\frac{\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{2}\right]}.$$

Hence

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v;\rho)=\Phi\left[\frac{\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right].$$

Now differentiate with respect to $v$ -- again using the above formula for the derivative of the inverse standard normal distribution function.

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u \partial v}C(u,v;\rho)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\frac{d}{dv}\Phi^{-1}(v)\Phi'\left[\frac{\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right]\\=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }\exp\left(-\frac{\Phi^{-1}(v)^2}{2}\right)\right]^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }\exp\left[\frac{-\Phi^{-1}(v)^2+2\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho^2\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right]\\=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left[\frac{-\rho^2\Phi^{-1}(v)^2+2\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho^2\Phi^{-1}(u)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right].$$

Comment: you are great! thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome again.

Comment: Dear friend, could you help me to solve this problem? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864564/how-to-compute-the-double-integral-of-gaussion-copula-in-matlab  thank you! I want to compute the integral of Gaussian copula in Matlab,but some mistakes occur.

Comment: Eric. I'll take a look and get back

Comment: Hi my friend, I appreciate your kind help! If you have any questions about above, please let me know.

Comment: @Eric Huang:  Your questions seem to be leading somewhere. I might be able to help if I knew more about your objective.  Are you trying to calculate $\int C(u,v)dC(u,v)$ for the Gaussian copula?

Comment: Thank for your kind help!!