# How to compute the double integral of Gaussion copula in matlab?

Tags: probability

**I want to compute the following expression:**
[image]

**The expression of Gaussion copula can be found here: [How to compute the seconds-order partial derivatives of Gaussion copula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864290/how-to-compute-the-seconds-order-partial-derivatives-of-gaussion-copula)**

When I was trying to compute the above expression in Matlab, I found that there exist some issues in the code of Gaussion copula. The error information is :"XMAX must be a floating point scalar.". could you help me to find the mistakes?

**The codes for Gaussion copula is following:**

syms x y alpha quantile current_q RHO df;

globaltau = 0.5;

RHO = sin(pi./2.*globaltau);

internalfunction = @(x,y) (1./(2.*pi.*(1-RHO.^2).^(0.5))).*exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2 - 2.*RHO.*x.*y)./(2.*(1-RHO.^2)));

GaussianCopula = @(x,y) integral2(internalfunction,-inf,norminv(x,0,1),-inf,norminv(y,0,1));

Tip: Maybe the above function of GaussianCopula is not right....

**The code for the seconds-order partial derivatives of u and v for Gaussion copula is following:**

diffxy = @(x,y)  (1-RHO.^2).^(-0.5).* exp((-RHO.^2.*norminv(x,0,1).^2-2.*RHO.*norminv(x,0,1).*norminv(y,0,1)-RHO.^2.*norminv(y,0,1).^2)./(2.*(1-RHO.^2)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are trying to find a measure of association (concordance) between random variables with a Gaussian copula as the dependence structure.

As an independent check and a somewhat easier numerical integration, evaluate the inner integral by parts

$$\int_{0}^{1}C(u,v)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u \partial v}C(u,v)\,du\\=\left.C(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C(u,v)\right|_{u=0}^{u=1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C(u,v)\,du\\=v-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C(u,v)\,du$$

Then

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}C(u,v)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u \partial v}C(u,v)\,dudv\\=\frac1{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v)\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C(u,v)\,dudv.$$

For the Gaussian copula, the first partial derivatives are given in terms of the standard normal distribution function $\Phi$ by

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(u,v)= \Phi\left[\frac{\Phi^{-1}(v)-\rho\Phi^{-1}(u)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right],\\\frac{\partial}{\partial v}C(u,v)= \Phi\left[\frac{\Phi^{-1}(u)-\rho\Phi^{-1}(v)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right].$$

The following MATLAB code should work for evaluating the integral

$$dc = @(x,y) ( normcdf((norminv(y)-rho.*norminv(x))./sqrt(1-rho.^2)) ).*( normcdf((norminv(x)-rho.*norminv(y))./sqrt(1-rho.^2)) )\\\\\ Q = integral2(dc,0,1,0,1)
$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.